# Mongoose TypeError: Rental is not a constructor

Tags: mongoose, typeerror

I am quite new to backend development and trying to import a Mongoose model and use it to write, then read from the database. If I import the model and try to use it, I get an error that it is not a constructor:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Rental is not a constructor
```

If I copy the model into the index file, it works fine.

I have seen some questions here with similar issues. Most of them exported the schema and not the model. I am trying to use the model and my capitalization between the model and the instance is correct.

The model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi')

const rentalSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    customer: {
        type: new mongoose.Schema({
            name: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                maxlength: 5
            },
            isGold: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            },
            phone: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                maxlength: 50
            }
        }),
        required: true
    },
    movie: {
        type: new mongoose.Schema({
            title: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
                trim: true,
                minlength: 5,
                maxlength: 255
            },
            dailyRentalRate: {
                type: Number,
                required: true,
                min: 0,
                max: 255
            }
        }),
        required: true
    },
    dateOut: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        default: Date.now
    },
    dateReturned: {
        type: Date
    },
    rentalFee: {
        type: Number,
        min: 0
    }
})

const Rental = mongoose.model('Rental', rentalSchema)

//...

module.exports = { Rental, validateObject }
```

The index file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', () => {
    console.log('Connected to Mongodb')
})

const Rental = require('./models/rental')
const customerId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId()
const movieId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId()

async function createRental() {
    const rental = new Rental({
        customer: {
            _id: customerId,
            name: '12345',
            phone: '12345'
        },
        movie: {
            _id: movieId,
            title: '12345',
            dailyRentalRate: 2
        }
    })
    await rental.save()

    console.log(rental)
}

async function getRental() {
    const rentalInDb = await Rental.findOne({
        'customer._id': customerId,
        'movie._id': movieId
    })

    console.log(rentalInDb)
}

createRental()
getRental()
```

I expected two console logs, instead I am getting a typeerror. Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you export your model like this:

```
module.exports = { Rental, validateObject }
```

You need to require it in this way:

```
const { Rental } = require('./models/rental')
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Thanks!